# Can't access method from another package by var.MethodName()

Tags: go

I have a package containing some structure and functions associated with it:

```
package samplepkg

type SampleStruct struct {
    FirstString string
    SecondString string
}

func init() {
    // some operations
}

func CheckSomething(s *SampleStruct) bool {
    // check something
}
```

Now I'm trying to run this function in another package:

```
import (
    "MyProject/samplepkg"
)

func testFunc() {
    var s = samplepkg.SampleStruct{"a", "b"}
    if s.CheckSomething() {
        // do some operations
    }
}
```

But I get an error that s.CheckSomething is undefined. (&s).CheckSomething gives the same result. I can access s.FirstString and s.SecondString as well as use this method by calling

```
if samplepkg.CheckSomething(&s) {
    // do some operations
}
```

But I feel it could be written in a better way. I'm aware that Go is not object-oriented language but is method invocation like this possible?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/1

Comment: You should use a method and not a function, then you'll be able to do `s.CheckSomething`.

Comment: `ChedkSomething()` is not a method receiver, so you obviously cannot call it on `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Golang a Method set is defined as:

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an
>   interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T
>   consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set
>   of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods
>   declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of T). Further rules apply to structs containing embedded fields,
>   as described in the section on struct types. Any other type has an
>   empty method set. In a method set, each method must have a unique
>   non-blank method name.

There is a mistake because you are using the pointer receiver with method when calling the function. So change the function when defining to method as:

```
func init() {
    // some operations
}

func(s *SampleStruct) CheckSomething() bool {
    // check something
}
```

Or when calling the method it should be function with argument `SampleStruct` which will be like

```
import (
    "MyProject/samplepkg"
)

func testFunc() {
    var s = &samplepkg.SampleStruct{"a", "b"}
    if CheckSomething(s) {
        // do some operations
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't differentiate between methods and functions in Golang yet. It works now, thanks